# How to not include quotes specified in set variable?

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, set, quotes

So i have written a simple batch script which allows me to launch a specific program with the parameters that i provide myself to choose from.

But i have some "set =" commands whose variables includes quotes in the strings.

Ex :

```
set engine="UnityCompilerDX11 v3.8.2"
```

Now as you can see i need the quotes to keep the string with Spaces (I know i can just use a UnderScore but i really don't want to) and when i use the variable to get the string in it's place i get the string with the quotes.

Ex :

```
echo %engine%
"UnityCompilerDx11 v3.8.2"
```

So basically i just wanted to know that how can i echo or use the variable's strings without quotes in or at a command.

Comment: [`set "engine=UnityCompilerDX11 v3.8.2"`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html).

Comment: @JosefZ Dang, it was that easy? Thanks.